# IntelliJ does not show compile errors in editor for a Gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, gradle

I have been trying to figure this out using Google search but haven't found even one article matching my question. When I import a Gradle project into IntelliJ (.ipr), I am not seeing that IntelliJ reports compile-time errors as and when I add content. This seriously limits me from using IntelliiJ's assists like adding import statements for classes. What needs to be done or configured so that IntelliJ starts reporting the compile-time errors as and when I add content?

Comment: Typically this works just fine, and I'm not aware of a general problem of that nature. Please provide more information such as Gradle version, IntelliJ version, relevant parts of build scripts and generated .ipr/.iml, how *exactly* you generate/import the project, etc.

Comment: Hi Peter, we are using project-specific gradle version 1.6 (although I have installed Gradle 2.0 separately in my system - not sure how to set IntelliJ to use project-specific Gradle), and I am using IntelliJ 13.1.5 Community Edition. we run gradlew idea (gradle wrapper) and then import .ipr file into intellij

Comment: I recommend to try and upgrade the project to a later Gradle version (1.6 is quite old). When generating IntelliJ files with `gradlew idea`, all that matters is the project's Gradle version - IntelliJ isn't aware of Gradle here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037440/intellij-idea-not-showing-errors-in-message-tool-window-after-gradle-build