# IntelliJ 2017.1 not showing Scala compilation messages (Gradle)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, compiler-errors

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.

The problem: After a Gradle build, I do not get a messages window that I can use to view all problems across the project. It is clear that the build failed because the run window shows a red exclamation point. Running `./gradlew build` from the terminal also fails. The issue is that IntelliJ is not interpreting/parsing the errors in way that shows up in the IDE.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Screenshot]

I've read the most popular posts here on Stack Overflow about IntelliJ not showing compilation errors, but they do not apply to my situation. Many are at least several years old -- they may not apply to recent versions of IDEA, Scala, and Gradle.

The closest match is [Intellij Idea not showing errors in Message Tool Window after Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037440/intellij-idea-not-showing-errors-in-message-tool-window-after-gradle-build):

> "In the top right corner of the "Run" window there is an odd looking button that when you mouse over is labeled "Toggle tasks executions/text mode."

However, that not directly address my concern, since it does not restore the functionality I was used to seeing in IntelliJ 2016. That is why I added this comment to the answer suggested above:

> Thanks -- your suggestion helps because it shows the command line error output. However, it doesn't show the error listing that I was used to seeing in IntelliJ 2016. Now that I'm using Gradle 3.4 and IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.1, I don't have a nice way to browse all project-wide compilation errors.

Any suggestions for workarounds or solutions?

My best guess at this point is that something changed in IntelliJ 2017.1. It was working in IntelliJ 2016.

Comment: I'm not having the same problem in a project that builds with [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org). Therefore, I think this problem is related to Gradle.

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.